# Maven: Invalid content was found starting with element "reportSets"

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

This is the javadoc plugin in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <id>PDF</id>
            <reports>
                <report>javadoc</report>
            </reports>
            <configuration>
                <name>PDF</name>
                <description>MovieList documentation</description>
                <destDir>pdf</destDir>
                <doclet>com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet</doclet>
                <docletPath>lib\pdfdoclet-1.0.3-all.jar</docletPath>
                <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                <additionalparam>
                    -pdf javadoc.pdf
                </additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

And it has an error on `<reportSets>`.

It says `Invalid content was found starting with element 'reportSets'`.

I'm trying to use this with the PDFDoclet jar but I can't manage to get it working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `<id>PDF</id>` is wrong....

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Simply remove it ....

Comment: @khmarbaise still shows the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure, but probably you did not put your `plugin` in proper element.
This should be in `<reporting>` element. It should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project ...>
...
    <reporting>
    ...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.4</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>PDF</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>javadoc</report>
                        </reports>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>PDF</name>
                            <description>MovieList documentation</description>
                            <destDir>pdf</destDir>
                            <doclet>com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet</doclet>
                            <docletPath>lib\pdfdoclet-1.0.3-all.jar</docletPath>
                            <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                            <additionalparam>
                                -pdf javadoc.pdf
                            </additionalparam>
                        </configuration>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    ...
    </reporting>
 ...
</project>
```

If you put this section in e.g.  section you got exactly error message like you have got - `Invalid content was found starting with element 'reportSets'`

Comment: I put it next to the other plugins in dependencies. After putting it in `<reporting>` how do I execute it?

Comment: Try executing `mvn site`.

Comment: `Cannot find doclet class com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet` but I downloaded the jar and made it a project library

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use their example from their website.

```
<ant:javadoc doclet="com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet"
        docletpath="./jar/pdfdoclet-1.0.0-all.jar"
        packagenames="com.jlaby.*"
        overview="./example/laby/overview_laby.html"
        additionalparam="-pdf ./example/results/laby.pdf -config ./example/laby/config_laby.properties"
        private="no"
        sourcepath="./example/laby" >
</ant:javadoc>
```

See http://pdfdoclet.sourceforge.net/running.html

Comment: where do I put this? If I have no maven.xml file do I create one in the project root?

Comment: See [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html) it shows where to put the chunk in your `pom.xml`. It should be in a `<task>` tag.